# Table and variable names - matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following `MATLAB` code:

```
clear; clc

Items = {'counter','item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'};

a = rand(8,4);
j = (1:8)';

t = table(j,a(:,1), a(:,2), a(:,3), a(:,4),'VariableNames',Items)
```

I would like to know if there is a sophisticated way to extend this list if i have e.g. 20 items. Following this code, I should include inside `table` every single `a(:,i), i = 1,...,20`, plus I would have to do the same for the `Items` list. I guess there is a more convenient way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html):

```
a = rand(8,4);

[l, w] = size(a);

j = 1:l;
Items = cell(1, w + 1);
Items{1} = 'counter';

for ii = 2:length(Items)
    Items{ii} = sprintf('item%u', ii - 1);
end

t = array2table([j', a], 'VariableNames', Items);
```

Edit: It seems like there's a lot of overhead associated with `array2table`. It's essentially a wrapper for `mat2cell` so there might be a speed benefit to just using that on its own and skipping all the error checking. Haven't tested it out though.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty neat solution (that's why the upvote), but how can `Items` list change in an automated way?

Comment: @thanasissdr sorry, I missed that part of the question. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make a cell with all columns in a.

```
for i=1:size(a,2)
acell{end+1}=a(:,i);
end
```

and then call

```
table(j,acell{:},'VariableNames',Items)
```

Here is an example:

```
Items = {'counter'};

a = rand(8,6);
j = (1:8)'

acell = [];

for i=1:size(a,2)
    acell{end+1}=a(:,i);
    Items{end+1}=['item',num2str(i)];
end
t = table(j,acell{:},'VariableNames',Items);
```

Comment: @simmons Did you try to run it? Something may be missing here.

Comment: I added a working example. You can change the shape of a and it should work.

Comment: You're resizing the cell array in every loop iteration which is extremely inefficient computationally. You know all the relevant dimensions to preallocate the array in memory and should do so.

Comment: Sure, but for any reasonable number of columns it really doesn't matter.